# Activity seems to finish directly on 2nd resume

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Let's pretend I have the activities `MyActivityA` and `MyActivityB`.

1. `MyActivityA` starts `MyActivityB`
2. `MyActivityB` starts an repeating AlarmManager who triggers an `IntentService` which is informing `MyActivityB` with a `ResultReceiver` when `something` happens.
3. `something` happened, `MyActivityB` opens an `AlertDialog`, the PositiveButton leads to `MyActivityA`

(`IntentService` makes GET-Requests, `something` is an expected GET-Response)

The first time it's working. But when I **then** repeat step one and two, the `AlertDialog` does not appear and the app crashes with `BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token ... is not valid; is your activity running?`

A check at step three showed, that `isFinishing()` is `true` the second time. That explains the error. But why is the activity finishing right after getting resumed?

I try to give you the relevant part of the code:

MyActivityA:

```
public class MyActivityA extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_a);
    }

    public void sendButtonPressed(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivityA.this, MyActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MyActivityB:

```
public class MyActivityB extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckIPResultReceiver.Receiver{

    private CheckIPResultReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_b);

        mReceiver = new CheckIPResultReceiver(new Handler());
        mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //starting repeated IntentService via AlarmManager
        String targetURL = "www.google.de";
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("targetURL", targetURL);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        //getting events from the service
        switch (resultCode) {
            case SendPostRequest_Service.STATUS_ALERT:

                //stopping AlarmManager
                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MyActivityB.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivityB.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                //debug-check
                if(isFinishing()){
                    // on the 2nd time --> TRUE!
                    Log.v(TAG, "Act. seems to finish?!");
                }
                else {
                    // only on the 1st time true
                    Log.v(TAG, "Act. seems ok");
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivityB.this)
                            .setTitle("Alert triggered!")
                            .setMessage("...")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivityB.this, MyActivityA.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions? I don't find any reason why `MyActivityB` goes into finishing...

Comment: So the first time does not finish but only the second?

Comment: I can see you had created mReceiver = new CheckIPResultReceiver, it is starts to do something. But where is a point, where mReceiver going to stop? In onClick you are finishing your activity, but mReceiver remains active, and will cause more unintended onReceiveResult execution.

Comment: You're calling `finish()` in `ActivityB` right after you use `startActivity(...)` to start `ActivityA`. Transitions from one `Activity` to another are actually synchronous and consequentially that means things aren't going to happen in the right order. In other words, when you call `finish()` in `ActivityB`, it won't actually be destroyed immediately. This means it is open to receiving more results from the `ResultReceiver` but at that point the `isFinishing()` method will return positive as the `Activity` has been flagged to indicate that `finish()` has been called.